# multicol and columnbreak how do I quell the vertical expansion/balance in one column?

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment

I am trying to end the text in one column and break to the second column w/o the first column getting "balanced". Here is an example.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[margin=1in, includefoot]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Southern Magic: Magic User}

\begin{multicols}{2}

\section{First Level}

\textbf{Ladder} (Alteration)
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{small}
    Range:          \emph{20 yds} \\
    Duration:       \emph{1 turn} \\
    Area of Effect: \emph{Special} \\
    \columnbreak
    Components:     \emph{V, S, M} \\
    Casting Time:   \emph{1 segment} \\
    Saving Throw:   \emph{None} \\
  \end{small}
\end{multicols}

The caster can use this spell to create a firmly anchored ladder of force, 1' wide, and 10' long 
plus 10' per level of the caster, to a maximum of 60'. This ladder is easy to climb (no dexterity 
check required).

The ladder may be used to climb walls and pits, or it may be laid horizontally and used to cross 
chasms. The material component is a knot of wood.

\columnbreak
\section{Fifth Level}

\textbf{Mummy} (Necromancy)
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{small}
    Range:          \emph{50 yds} \\
    Duration:       \emph{1 turn/level} \\
    Area of Effect: \emph{Special} \\
    \columnbreak
    Components:     \emph{V, S, M} \\
    Casting Time:   \emph{5 segments} \\
    Saving Throw:   \emph{None} \\
  \end{small}
\end{multicols}

With this spell, the mage can animate one corpse for every four levels of experience he possesses. 
These corpses have all the characteristics and abilities, including hit points, of a mummy.

When the spell's duration has expired or the mummies are slain, the corpses crumble to dust. The 
material component is mummy dust.

\section{Seventh Level}

\textbf{Time Loop} (Alteration)
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{small}
    Range:          \emph{Self} \\
    Duration:       \emph{1 round/level} \\
    Area of Effect: \emph{10' cube} \\
    \columnbreak
    Components:     \emph{V, S, M} \\
    Casting Time:   \emph{7 segments} \\
    Saving Throw:   \emph{Special} \\
  \end{small}
\end{multicols}

This spell creates an area where the flow of time repeats itself continuously, until the duration 
of the spell (as timed in the outside word) expires.

Creatures caught in the time loop see the world as flickering chaos and are unable to affect it in 
any way. Anyone outside the loop perceives those trapped within as endlessly repeating one set of 
actions; those outside may affect the beings within the time loop with ranged spells and attacks, 
but if they physically enter it, they too are trapped.

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

A screenshot of the behavior is provided below. How do I keep the left column from expanding to match the right, vertically? I would prefer to have a bunch of empty space below the entry on the left.

[image: spell list]

Possibly the same effect is seen below, at the end of a chapter. I would prefer all the text to be in the left column, instead of being split between the columns.
[image: end of chapter]

Comment: `\raggedbottom` will result in all extra space being placed at the bottom.

Comment: I tried `\raggedbottom` but it had no effect in this context. Note that the sample code above is from a much larger document with a lot of preamble, so something may be colliding with `\raggedbottom`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay so this can be handled rather straight-forwardly.  First, we'll evoke the twocolumn option in the report class and then we remove the outermost multicols. If you still want control of when you \columnbreak (something that only works in multicols) then use page break.  Adjusted document below:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{report}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[margin=1in, includefoot]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Southern Magic: Magic User}



\section{First Level}

\textbf{Ladder} (Alteration)
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{small}
    Range:          \emph{20 yds} \\
    Duration:       \emph{1 turn} \\
    Area of Effect: \emph{Special} \\
    \columnbreak
    Components:     \emph{V, S, M} \\
    Casting Time:   \emph{1 segment} \\
    Saving Throw:   \emph{None} \\
  \end{small}
\end{multicols}

The caster can use this spell to create a firmly anchored ladder of force, 1' wide, and 10' long 
plus 10' per level of the caster, to a maximum of 60'. This ladder is easy to climb (no dexterity 
check required).

The ladder may be used to climb walls and pits, or it may be laid horizontally and used to cross 
chasms. The material component is a knot of wood.

\section{Fifth Level}

\textbf{Mummy} (Necromancy)
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{small}
    Range:          \emph{50 yds} \\
    Duration:       \emph{1 turn/level} \\
    Area of Effect: \emph{Special} \\
    \columnbreak
    Components:     \emph{V, S, M} \\
    Casting Time:   \emph{5 segments} \\
    Saving Throw:   \emph{None} \\
  \end{small}
\end{multicols}

With this spell, the mage can animate one corpse for every four levels of experience he possesses. 
These corpses have all the characteristics and abilities, including hit points, of a mummy.

When the spell's duration has expired or the mummies are slain, the corpses crumble to dust. The 
material component is mummy dust.
\pagebreak
\section{Seventh Level}

\textbf{Time Loop} (Alteration)
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{small}
    Range:          \emph{Self} \\
    Duration:       \emph{1 round/level} \\
    Area of Effect: \emph{10' cube} \\
    \columnbreak
    Components:     \emph{V, S, M} \\
    Casting Time:   \emph{7 segments} \\
    Saving Throw:   \emph{Special} \\
  \end{small}
\end{multicols}

This spell creates an area where the flow of time repeats itself continuously, until the duration 
of the spell (as timed in the outside word) expires.

Creatures caught in the time loop see the world as flickering chaos and are unable to affect it in 
any way. Anyone outside the loop perceives those trapped within as endlessly repeating one set of 
actions; those outside may affect the beings within the time loop with ranged spells and attacks, 
but if they physically enter it, they too are trapped.



\end{document}
```

ALTERNATIVELY, if you want to keep the multicol just use \vspace{\fill} before column breaks like this. You should note that the 2-column description of the spell doesn't break where you want it to break.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[margin=1in, includefoot]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Southern Magic: Magic User}

\begin{multicols}{2}

\section{First Level}

\textbf{Ladder} (Alteration)\\
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{small}
    Range:          \emph{20 yds} \\
    Duration:       \emph{1 turn} \\
    Area of Effect: \emph{Special} \\

    \columnbreak
    Components:     \emph{V, S, M} \\
    Casting Time:   \emph{1 segment} \\
    Saving Throw:   \emph{None} \\
  \end{small}
\end{multicols}

The caster can use this spell to create a firmly anchored ladder of force, 1' wide, and 10' long 
plus 10' per level of the caster, to a maximum of 60'. This ladder is easy to climb (no dexterity 
check required).\\

The ladder may be used to climb walls and pits, or it may be laid horizontally and used to cross 
chasms. The material component is a knot of wood.
\vspace*{\fill}
\columnbreak
\section{Fifth Level}

\textbf{Mummy} (Necromancy)
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{small}
    Range:          \emph{50 yds} \\
    Duration:       \emph{1 turn/level} \\
    Area of Effect: \emph{Special} \\
    
    \columnbreak
    Components:     \emph{V, S, M} \\
    Casting Time:   \emph{5 segments} \\
    Saving Throw:   \emph{None} \\
  \end{small}
\end{multicols}

With this spell, the mage can animate one corpse for every four levels of experience he possesses. 
These corpses have all the characteristics and abilities, including hit points, of a mummy.

When the spell's duration has expired or the mummies are slain, the corpses crumble to dust. The 
material component is mummy dust.

\section{Seventh Level}

\textbf{Time Loop} (Alteration)
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{small}
    Range:\emph{Self}\\    
    Duration: \emph{1 rnd/level} \\    
    Area of Effect: \emph{10' cube} 
    
    \columnbreak
    Components:     \emph{V, S, M} \\
    Casting Time:   \emph{7 segments} \\
    Saving Throw:   \emph{Special} \\
  \end{small}
\end{multicols}

This spell creates an area where the flow of time repeats itself continuously, until the duration 
of the spell (as timed in the outside word) expires.

Creatures caught in the time loop see the world as flickering chaos and are unable to affect it in 
any way. Anyone outside the loop perceives those trapped within as endlessly repeating one set of 
actions; those outside may affect the beings within the time loop with ranged spells and attacks, 
but if they physically enter it, they too are trapped.
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `small` resets the font size within the `\begin ... \end` environment.  There isn't actually a `small` environment, but this formulation works.

Comment: Sweet - thanks! The `\vspace*{\fill}` is exactly what I am looking for. As a bonus it works with `\pagebreak` as well. I can live with the vertical balance/reflow at the end of `Time Loop` above, that's ok. I can't apply `twocolumn` to the report class like that as most of the document is one column, but thanks for that. I didn't know I could do that!

Comment: @barbara beeton it's a convenient hack I use frequently for localized font size changes.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that `multicols` environments are well suited for the job at hand. Here's an alternative solution, which uses side-by-side `tabular` environments encased in `center` environments.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{multicol,array}
\usepackage[letterpaper, margin=1in, includefoot]{geometry}

\newcommand\mytab[1]{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{} r >{\em}l @{}} #1 \end{tabular}}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Southern Magic: Magic User}

\begin{multicols}{2}

\section{First Level}

\textbf{Ladder} (Alteration)

\begin{center}
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\small
\mytab{ Range &          20 yds \\
        Duration &       1 turn \\
        Area of Effect & Special }
\quad
\mytab{ Components &     V, S, M   \\
        Casting Time &   1 segment \\
        Saving Throw &   None }
\end{center}

The caster can use this spell to create a firmly anchored ladder of force, 1' wide, and 10' long  plus 10' per level of the caster, to a maximum of 60'. This ladder is easy to climb (no dexterity check required).

The ladder may be used to climb walls and pits, or it may be laid horizontally and used to cross chasms. The material component is a knot of wood.


\section{Fifth Level}

\textbf{Mummy} (Necromancy)

\begin{center}
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\small
\mytab{ Range &          50 yds \\
        Duration &       1 turn/level \\
        Area of Effect & Special
}
\quad
\mytab{ Components &     V, S, M \\
        Casting Time &   5 segments \\
        Saving Throw &   None 
}
\end{center}

With this spell, the mage can animate one corpse for every four levels of experience he possesses. These corpses have all the characteristics and abilities, including hit points, of a mummy.

When the spell's duration has expired or the mummies are slain, the corpses crumble to dust. The material component is mummy dust.


\section{Seventh Level}

\textbf{Time Loop} (Alteration)

\begin{center}
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\small
\mytab{ Range &          Self \\
        Duration &       1 round/level \\
        Area of Effect & 10' cube }
\quad
\mytab{ Components &     V, S, M \\
        Casting Time &   7 segments \\
        Saving Throw &   Special } 
\end{center}

This spell creates an area where the flow of time repeats itself continuously, until the duration of the spell (as timed in the outside word) expires.

Creatures caught in the time loop see the world as flickering chaos and are unable to affect it in any way. Anyone outside the loop perceives those trapped within as endlessly repeating one set of actions; those outside may affect the beings within the time loop with ranged spells and attacks, but if they physically enter it, they too are trapped.

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I went with MathBioGuy's post below as the multicolumn sections of this document tend to span pages. I have worked with multi-page tables in auto-gen'd reports before but would prefer to stick with `multicolumn` here. However, I DO like the table idea for the "components", etc, so I am going with that -thanks!